# The "A day in the penalty box" needs a comments cleanup, and better curation

Tags: discussion, status-review, blog

There's a proper, fairly well documented process of appealing a suspension - via moderator message replies or the contact pages.

For some reason, folks, including many who know how things work, have been treating the comments to [A Day in the Penalty Box](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) as a complaints box.

While the comments on the blog are moderated, the 80 or so comments on this blog are people begging for remissions on suspensions that ended years ago, people ranting about various decisions, or occasionally just unhinged rants.

It's a bit of a bad look.

While I do realise that the blog is run under different standards, it feels quite unfortunate to allow what feels like a festering pool of toxicity linger in a page we often link suspended users to to understand what's happening to them, more so when specific users seem to have been named.

Could we get these comments cleaned up, and maybe have the folks maintaining the blog have a quick word with the community team over standards, and maintain these standards?

Comment: At a glance, pretty much all of the comments there should be nuked... And some of'm investigated for sockpuppeting...

Comment: Well sure. Though considering the age of many of these, there might no longer be a point in investigating

Comment: It's probably "Gets suspended" -> "Clicks blog link in suspension message" -> "Rants in comments about suspension being incorrect". We might want to link to a help center page instead of the blog in the suspension message to reduce the amount of spam.

Comment: @ErikA That's probably a feature request all on its own

Comment: @ErikA or even better, don't let suspended users comment, now that the blog requires SO account in order to comment.

Comment: My chat account has been in "rolling" timed suspension for the past few years, so the part that says "*At the end of this timed suspension period, your reputation will be recalculated, and your account will resume as normal. **We don't hold grudges**. The point of all this is to address the behavior. If the behavior improves, you are welcome back."* should also get nuked since it's a load of cobblers.

Comment: Somehow I don't think posting the exact same sort of comment I was complaining under my post was what I had in mind here when posting that.